# UINavigation bar does not reload the first view

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have a nav controller app with two views, the first view is a table view, clicking on a row loads a uiwebview. The web view loads correctly and the back button appears, clicking the back button, changes only the nav bar but does not reload the first view (table view).

My understanding that the "nav back" was automatic, but obviously I have missed something.

This is the code that call the webview in the didselectrowatindexpath method

```
 DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc]           
 initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
 [dvController release];
```

Comment: could you elaborate on how you load/present/push/add the uiwebview?

Comment: i edited the question, and added the code to reply to the comment.
    \

Comment: and the uiwebview is defined in the xib file, no other relevant code touching it?

Comment: Yes. the uiwebview in a xib, no other code touching it, and it displays correctly, clicking the nav back button while in the webview, changes the nav bar but does not reload the table.

Comment: and why *should* it reload the table? Does the webview vanish and is the table visible again? What exactly do you expect?

Comment: Pass in nil for the bundle param btw -- this causes the main bundle to be used.

Comment: @mvds - I thought he meant that too, but now I think he means that the initial table view doesn't appear at all when he presses 'Back', and the web view remains. Is this the case, Tori?

Comment: @occulus. Yes, you are correct. At launch, the table view is visible. Once a row is selected, the web view appears. Clicking on the back button in the nav bar, changes the nav bar but keeps the web view and the table view is not reloaded. This is what I would like to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to reload your table view when the first view appears. Try something like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```